# How to access a External class member inside a android Service?

Tags: java, android

Basically I have a android Service *LogService* which I trigger from my MainActivity. Inside service class I am creating a object of LocationListener class *LocationFetcher* with the name locationFetcher. The *LocationFetcher* class has a public string member *FormattedResult*. Now Inside the LogService.run() I want to fetch FormattedResult periodically. How to do That ?? Below is code for reference.

I have a LocationListener like This:

```
/*This is relevant content of LocationFetcher.java */

public class LocationFetcher extends TimerTask implements LocationListener{

    public String FormattedResult;
    private boolean availableFlag;
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.availableFlag=true;
        this.FormattedResult=String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Lat=\t%f\nLong=\t%f", arg0.getLatitude(),arg0.getLongitude());
        Log.d("LocationFetcher",this.FormattedResult);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("LocationFetcher","This is Timer Run !!!");
    }}
```

My android service is like this :

```
/* This is the relevant pert from LogService.java file*/

public class LogService extends Service{
    private Logger logger;
    private LocationFetcher locationFetcher;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    private Timer timer1;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if(!this.running){

        this.logger = new Logger();  //Initiated member from subclass
        this.logger.start();         //Started
        this.timer1 = new Timer();   //Timer for timed job          
        this.locationFetcher = new LocationFetcher();//THIS IS MY EXTERNAL CLASS in "LocationFetcher.java"  
                                      //I am using GPS data.
        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(this.locationFetcher != null){//NULLPointerException is thrown if I REMOVE this if ??WHY
            this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this.locationFetcher);
            this.timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(this.locationFetcher, 5000, 2000); 
         //Below Line still throws NullPointrException ??WHY
         //this.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this.locationFetcher);

        }else{
            Log.d("GPS-Logger"," Found Null LocationFlecther !");
        }
    }
    public void run(){
        LogService ll = LogService.this;
        LocationManager mgr = ll.locationManager; //THIS IS MY QUESTION
        // HOW DO I ACCESS THE GPS LOCATION STORED in locationmanager.FormattedResult
        // Which is a string
        // //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        while(ll.isActive){

            try {

                String temp ;
                if(!temp.isEmpty()){
                    Log.d("GPS-Logger","data is :"+temp);
                }
                Log.d("GPS-Logger","data is :");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                sec +=1 ;
                if(sec >= 12){
                    Log.d("GPS-Logger","Sending Data Here");
                    sec = 0;
                }

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ll.isActive=false;
                Log.d("GPS-Logged","EXIT Request Received");
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that I have asked multiple Questions above but I didn't knew how to separate them.
NEED HELP!!!

Comment: public static String FormattedResult;// make it static  Then in you Service Class access the string as LocationFetcher.FormattedResult.

Comment: locationFetcher.FormattedResult

Comment: Forget the `static` recommendations, they're dangerous if you don't understand what you're doing. @HoanNguyen is right. By the way, don't use timers on Android, `post()` `Runnable`s via `Handler`s or `View` convenience functions instead. A `Timer` is a separate `Thread` which is a very inefficient approach on Android.

Comment: @ArpitGarg always returnig me null. Also note that I am accessing it as String temp = LocationFetcher.FormattedResult. Is it logical to make this string static when LocationListener will be uploading it with latest lat long ?

Comment: @wy yes it is advised here to go for static ... also onLocationChanged would only call when location is changed and your FormattedResult will be null only... So grab the location by location listener

Comment: @ArpitGarg I don't want to implement LocationListener in Service! If nothing works I will do that.

Comment: @wy I am not suggesting to implement it in Service. The LocationFetcher that you have made is not grabbing the location cordinates and the last known location.. It will return null only

Comment: @ArpitGarg That does it. sorry for the confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have the location Fetcher modified as "LocationListenerClass" shown below:

The main concern to see in the modified class are as follows:

1.I have used a singleton class for registering and removing location updates from overall      area.(i.e say our service etc).

2.**You should initialize the location string say (FormattedResult as in you case ) from both onLocationChngaed() and getCurrentLocation(). Because onLocationChngaed() will only call when the distance and time changed as provided in [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper%29) study more about this.**

```
    public class LocationListenerClass implements LocationListener{
        private static LocationListenerClass instance;
        private static Context context;
        private LocationManager myLocationManager;
        private LocationListener myLocationListener;
        private Double latitude = 0d;
        private Double longitude = 0d;
public static String FormattedResult;
        public static LocationListenerClass getInstance(Context context) {
            LocationListenerClass.context = context;
            if (null == instance) {
                instance = new LocationListenerClass();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void getCurrentLocation() {
            try {
                myLocationManager = (LocationManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 100,
                        this);

                Location location;
                location = myLocationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if (location == null) {
                    myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100,
                            myLocationListener);
                    location = myLocationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }

                if (location != null) {
                    try {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        Data.CURENT_LATITUDE = latitude;
                        Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, " latitude : "
                                + Data.CURENT_LATITUDE);
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE = longitude;
                        Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, " longitude : "
                                + Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE);

 **FormattedResult=String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Lat=\t%f\nLong=\t%f", latitude(),longitude());
        Log.d("LocationFetcher",this.FormattedResult);**

                    } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        public void removeLocationUpdates() {
            try {
                if (myLocationManager != null) {
                    myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }



            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                try {
                    if (location != null) {
                        Data.CURENT_LATITUDE = location.getLatitude();
                        Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, "LOCATION CHANGED" + " latitude : "
                                + Data.CURENT_LATITUDE);
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE = location.getLongitude();
                        Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, "LOCATION CHANGED" + " longitude : "
                                + Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE);

 **FormattedResult=String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Lat=\t%f\nLong=\t%f", latitude(),longitude());
        Log.d("LocationFetcher",this.FormattedResult);**
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        }
```